# Convert numpy array with floats to binary (0 or 1 integers)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an input array that looks like this:

```
  [[  0.    1. ]
   [ 10.    0.4]
   [ 20.    1.4]
   [ 30.    3. ]
   [ 40.    1.1]
   [ 50.    0.7]]
```

Now I'd like to convert the float values from the second column (the ones in array[:, 1]) to single bit binary values represented as 1 or 0 integers. I have threshold value that I'd like to use as a limit between logical 0 and logical 1. Let's say it is 1.5. After the conversion the array should look like this:

```
  [[  0.    0 ]
   [ 10.    0]
   [ 20.    0]
   [ 30.    1]
   [ 40.    0]
   [ 50.    0]]
```

How do I do that with the least effort?

Comment: To put actual integer values in the array (as opposed to float `1.0`) you have switch to a structured array, or just put the binary values in a separate array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compare the second column against the threshold, which would be a boolean array and then assign it back to the second column. The assignment would upcast it to float data before assigning back. The resultant second column would still be `float`, but as `0s` and `1s` as it needs to maintain the datatype there.

Thus, simply do -

```
a[:,1] = a[:,1]>1.5
```

Sample run -

```
In [47]: a
Out[47]: 
array([[  0. ,   1. ],
       [ 10. ,   0.4],
       [ 20. ,   1.4],
       [ 30. ,   3. ],
       [ 40. ,   1.1],
       [ 50. ,   0.7]])

In [48]: a[:,1] = a[:,1]>1.5

In [49]: a
Out[49]: 
array([[  0.,   0.],
       [ 10.,   0.],
       [ 20.,   0.],
       [ 30.,   1.],
       [ 40.,   0.],
       [ 50.,   0.]])
```

Comment: To be even more precise: The result of `a[:,1]>1.5` is a boolean array, but the assignment converts it back to float.

Comment: @Trilarion Right. Added that.

Comment: Yes, it's a boolean array. For instance a = a[:, 1]>1.5 results in [False False False True False False]. But as I need to do math with these values I need them to be integers. But a[:, 1] = a[:, 1]>1.5 works.